# Evaluating: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{\cosh(kx)}dx}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

How can you integrate: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\dfrac{1}{\cosh(kx)}dx}$$

I know that:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dfrac{1}{\cosh(x)}dx}=\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dfrac{2}{e^x+e^{-x}}dx}=\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dfrac{2e^{-x}}{1+e^{-2x}}dx}=$$
$$=2\int_{0}^{\infty}{(1-1/3+1/5-1/7+...)dx}=2\pi/4=\pi/2$$

But i don´t know how to integrate:
 $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\dfrac{1}{\cosh(kx)}dx}$$

Comment: Use the substitution $u=e^x$

Comment: @JacksonFitzsimmons, i used it, and i get: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\dfrac{2}{u(e^k+e^{-k})}dx}$

Comment: Why don't you use the substitution $y = kx$?  Then you will get the answer immediately from what you already know.  Also @JacksonFitzsimmons idea will compute the indefinite integral of $1/\cosh(x)$.  Also, when you used his substitution, you made a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to collect all the contributions from @marty cohen and @Stephen Montgomery-Smith, i will write the answer:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dfrac{1}{\cosh(x)}dx}=\pi /2$$

Let $u=kx\implies du=kdx\implies dx=\dfrac{1}{k}du$

Substituting:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\dfrac{1}{\cosh(kx)}dx}=\dfrac{1}{k}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\dfrac{1}{\cosh(u)}du}$$

Since 
$\cosh(u)
=\cosh(-u)\implies \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{\cosh(u)}du
=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{\cosh(u)}du$

So:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\dfrac{1}{\cosh(kx)}dx}=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{\cosh(u)}du=\dfrac{\pi}{k}$$

Answer (score 5):

Since 
$\cosh(x)
=\cosh(-x)
$,
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
=2\int_{0}^{\infty}
$.

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{\cosh(kx)}
=\frac1{k}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{kdx}{\cosh(kx)}
=\frac1{k}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{\cosh(x)}
$

Comment: how i can ensure: $\dfrac{k}{\cosh{kx}}=\dfrac{1}{\cosh{x}}$?

Comment: You don't.  But notice the $1/k$ outside the second expression.

Comment: Yes, but check in the third integral, that k vanishes.

Comment: It's actually a substitution kx |-> x